# VSCode+WSL2+JupyterLabでステップ実行する方法

Tags: python3, vscode, jupyter-lab

VSCodeで、WSL2リモート接続プラグイン + Jupyter Labプラグインを利用しています。
このPython実行環境でステップ実行するための設定方法を教えてもらえませんか？

[VSCode上のJupyter Notebookはブレークポイントを使ったデバッグができるようになっていた][2]

上記ページを参考に、`<プロジェクトディレクトリ>/.vscode/settings.json` ファイルに、`"jupyter.experimental.debugging": true` と追加しましたが、デバッグ機能が有効になりませんでした。

---

◇追記（その１）
WSL2ではないローカル環境(Windows10)で、記事の通りにやってみました。

記事の「右上のファイルに矢印が付いているマーク」より、ファイル
「C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json」
が開いたので、
"jupyter.experimental.debugging": true
を追加しました。

さらに、venv仮想環境作成後に、
pip install --upgrade ipykernel
↑のコマンドで、ipykernelを更新しました。

その後、VSCode右上のPython実行環境を選択しましたが、
（Ver6以上ipykernelがどれか分からないのですべて選択して試しました。）
Debugアイコンが出現しませんでした。

◇追記（その２）
どのような環境で実行しましたか？

1. Jupyter Labはどのようにインストールしましたか？
   VSCodeのプラグイン「Jupyter v2023.3.1000892223」を追加インストールしました。
2. pythonファイルの実行方法は？
   *.ipynbファイルを作成後、セルを選択状態で、ctrl+enterキー押下により実行しました。
3. リモート接続プラグインを使用していますが､リモートエクスプローラーでファイルを開きましたか？
   はい、リモートエクスプローラでipythonファイルを開きました。
   （VSCodeのプラグイン「WSL v0.77.0」を追加インストールしています。このプラグインでリモートエクスプローラが利用できるようになるのですよね？）

◇参考情報１
WSL2環境で*.pyファイルの、ステップ実行はできました。VSCodeの左側メニュー「実行とデバッグ」欄の機能は正しく動作しているようです。

Comment: ちなみに、記事のとおりの環境(WSL2ではないローカル？)でやってみたことはありますか？ その時の動作可否や状況の情報を追記すると何か応答が得られ易いかもしれません。

Comment: どのような環境で実行しましたか？
1. Jupyter Labはどのようにインストールしましたか？
2. pythonファイルの実行方法は？
3. リモート接続プラグインを使用していますが､リモートエクスプローラーでファイルを開きましたか？
などです

Comment: 質問欄に、「記事のとおりの環境での挙動」、「どのような環境で実行したか」について追記しました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: まず「WSL2リモート接続」でない*普通の環境で*構築したほうがよいのでは？ それができないのにあれこれ手を付けても仕方ないように思いますが。[Notebookで Debugはこちら](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_debug-a-jupyter-notebook) (昔の, 個人的な記事参照するより, 本来のサイト見るべきでしょう。settings.json編集しろとは書いてない)

Comment: <https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_debug-a-jupyter-notebook>の
[Debug a Jupyter Notebook]章の[Debug Cell]欄の通りに実施することで、ステップ実行できました。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: もしかしたらこちらの記事の方が環境的に参考になるのかもしれませんね。[VS Codeからリモートサーバー上のJupyterLabにアタッチしてデバッグを行う手順](https://qiita.com/nognog/items/3b9215509c065fb82e2a), [VS Code Remote Development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview), [Python debugging in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging)